# Dim/hide logging lines of code in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

Is there any way to make visual studio dim or hide/show on demand logging lines of my code?
We use a lot of logging in our project and it's harder to read code like this.

I would like it to be like this, for example:

[image: I would like it to be like this, for example:]

Answer (score 8):

Unobtrusive Code extension worked for me for Visual Studio 2019. It dims the opacity of log lines (and comments, which I disabled - I enjoy reading my comments). He did a quick update for the nuget package, and it works great.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=niklaskallander.UnobtrusiveCode

Comment: Just what I was looking for. Can be customised to also allow for dimming of Trace statements. Have set them to be 0.1 opacity which is almost invisible. Hold down the shift key and the opacity temporarily goes back to 1.0 so you can read them. Thx.

Answer (score 5):

I use this. Hoping one day they will add color customization and line selection regex options as well:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ElmarXCV.GrayLogLines

Comment: This is only compatible with Visual Studio 17 & doesn't work with Visual Studio 19 - You'll have to use "Unobtrusive Code" extension instead

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this from the standard Visual Studio IDE.  In order to do this you would need to define a custom extension which recognized lines like this, tagged them with a specific format and have that format be colored a lighter color in the IDE

Comment: Yeah, i supposed someone knows a plugin like that

Comment: @Anri I don't believe one exists that is generally available. I think R# will do something along these lines for certain code paths.  I don't know of one that is configurable though

Answer (score 0):

a "hackier" way would be to wrap all logging in a preprocessor directive like

```
#if DEBUG
Log.Info(........)
#endif
```

Visual-Studio will "dim" the code inside.
and have some kind of config header where you

```
#define DEBUG 0
```

Not the prettiest but its nice if you don't want debug code compiled into your Release binary

Answer (score -3):

why don't you put your section within #region tag.

E.G:

```
     #region Put some region name here for your reference
          Your Code / Comment / Whatever
     #endregion
```