# Hide/fold/dim arbitrary lines of code by regex (e.g. to hide logging)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

There is a lot of logging in my C++ project. The logging is done via a log stream and the log lines have the following format:

```
APP_LOG_XXX() << ... ;
```

Those log lines blend with the rest of the code and make it harder to be read.

I want to somehow make these log lines appear in dimmed colors, or even better to hide/fold by a hotkey or click. There are a lot of log lines already, so wrapping them up in `#pragma region` would take much time (or would require writing a separate script). I wonder if there is an easier way.

(There is a very [similar question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15209471/23715), but it's about Visual Studio, not Visual Studio Code).

Comment: @Mark the question was about automatic hiding/folding/dimming by regex, not manual by hand.

Comment: You say "or even better to hide/fold by a hotkey or click" - that isn't by hand?

Comment: @Mark I meant to fold/unfold all of them at once by a hotkey or click. As I understand the answer you linked assumed first selecting all the needed lines by hand. Sorry for being not clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use extension [Highlight](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=fabiospampinato.vscode-highlight).

Set the color to a version close to your theme background color

Add to your `settings.json`

```json
  "highlight.regexes": {
    "(APP_LOG_XXX\\(\\) <<[^;]+;)": {
      "regexFlags": "mg",
      "decorations": [
        { "color": "#f0f0f0" }
      ]
    }
  }
```

Or you can use the `opacity` [decoration property](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#DecorationRenderOptions.opacity) instead. The following configuration will dim the text while preserving its current syntax highlighting:

```json
  "highlight.regexes": {
    "(APP_LOG_XXX\\(\\) <<[^;]+;)": {
      "regexFlags": "mg",
      "decorations": [
        { "opacity": "0.4" }
      ]
    }
  }
```

Comment: Works great! What I'm missing, though, is the ability to just change the current text opacity, instead of changing the text color altogether (this would allow to keep current syntax highlighting). And also it would be nice to have an option to don't highlight whitespaces (since I have the `View -> Render Whitespace` vscode option turned on, and thus all my whitespaces marks change their color as well).

Comment: So, I've found out that there actually exists the "opacity" decoration in the VSCode API and it does exactly what I want. Using "opacity" : "0.4" will dim the text while preserving its current syntax highlighting.

Comment: I've edited your answer to add the example with the opacity property for the sake of other interested users. Hope you don't mind. Thanks!

Comment: This is AMAZING! Thank you! Here is mine: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65704132/470749